# iOS app builds even after all the frameworks have been removed from the XCode project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, frameworks

I read about some of the basic frameworks that are required for creating a simple iOS app and I deduced that to make an iOS app with nothing more than a empty window, the least I require are the Foundation framework and the UIKit framework. So I created an Empty Project for iOS in XCode that does nothing more than display an empty window and then proceeded to remove the frameworks from both the frameworks directory and even from the Build Phases and tried building it and it still built and ran the project successfully. I tried removing the pre-compiled header that is generated in the project automatically and tried again and it still built successfully. I even tried to comment the #import in main.m and the app delegate's header and tried to compile and it still succeeded. I was expecting it to throw some error saying that the frameworks are required but it didn't.

As per my understanding, the Foundation framework includes all the basic classes including the root NSObject class and the UIKit includes all UI related classes. So how can I have a project that displays an empty window run without these two frameworks? Or am I not removing the frameworks the right way or are they implicitly included in some way? How do I remove them properly?

Comment: you can not delete framework you can just remove reference only of that framework.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the import line, to be able to use those frameworks.
If it's working for you, probably it's because it's already compiled. Try to clean the derived data of the project (from Organizer->Projects).

Another option is to use the new modules notation in iOS 7 to add a Cocoa framework

```
@import UIKit;
```